# Should I use base classes or child classes to access enum values/constants defined in base classes?

Tags: c++, class, enums, scope, constants

Let's say we have two classes, `Base` and `Child`. `Child` inherits `Base`. `Value` is a constant variable (or a enum value) defined in `Base`, so it can be accessed by `Base::Value`.

Now we are dealing with some variables of type `Child`. I notice that in many documents and sample codes, people tend to use `Base::Value` instead of `Child::Value` though they are dealing with `Child` instances. For example, in Qt library there are `QIODevice` and `QBuffer` (the later is a child of the former), and `QBuffer` has a method `open`. The documents tend to use something like `buffer.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite, ...);` instead of `buffer.open(QBuffer::ReadWrite, ...);`. There are many other examples I believe you all have seen frequently.

I'm a bit curious why people tend to use the base classes to access those values, since sometimes we don't know for sure in which classes is the value defined, and more importantly, it is possible that the child classes may override the values defined in base classes. So isn't it the best to access constant values through the current class (`WhateverClassBeingUsed::Value`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm a bit curious why people tend to use the base classes to access
>   those variables, since sometimes we don't know for sure in which
>   classes is the value defined, and more importantly, it is possible
>   that the child classes may override the values defined in base
>   classes.

Sure, but both of these scenarios are hideously bad code and you want to *avoid* them. You cannot override the value of an enum, you could only define a coincidentally-named enum. It would be a totally different type and it would not compile.

Not knowing for sure in which class it's defined is only useful for implementation details... the user has to know which class to use, so they find out and then they use it.

There's no genuine loss by using the class in which the enum is defined.

Comment: It does [compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ecd55fb76fd6a91b) since names in derived hide the names in base. But yes, that's hideous.

Comment: @T.C.: You forgot the part where he passes it to another function. [Doesn't work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dc16484c422657a3).

Comment: @Puppy: Ah, right, if the function takes the enum type. If it takes an `int` or if it's a `static const int` instead of an enum it'd compile.

Comment: @Kerrek: Yep. The avatar's the clue here :P